# Magento 2 Checkout.Validate current form

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have additional input and select fields in shipping method.

In checkout at shipping step all forms validates by this code:

module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

```
            saveNewAddress: function () {
                var addressData,
                newShippingAddress;

            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.data.validate');

            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                addressData = this.source.get('shippingAddress');
                // if user clicked the checkbox, its value is true or false. Need to convert.
                addressData.save_in_address_book = this.saveInAddressBook ? 1 : 0;

                // New address must be selected as a shipping address
                newShippingAddress = createShippingAddress(addressData);
                selectShippingAddress(newShippingAddress);
                checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(newShippingAddress.getKey());
                checkoutData.setNewCustomerShippingAddress(addressData);
                this.getPopUp().closeModal();
                this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
            }
        }
```

This code triggers all inputs and selects on shipping step

```
            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.data.validate');
```

I want to validate only

```
          <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-list-additional-               addresses') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
```

in shipping.html

This is UiClass  registry.get('index = address-list-additional-addresses');

---

Code

```
            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.source.trigger('address-list-additional-addresses.data.validate');
```

Fires nothing.

Thanks for your answers:)

Comment: I need to validade checkout form I am autocompleting it but when I hit button next even thought is populated it says it's required have you found a solution to validate?thanks

Comment: Sorry I tried this but I don't know why the billing and shipping address wasn't available when I login...